# How to transform superscript number to real number in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

How can you transform a string containing a superscript to normal string?

For example I have a string containing `"n⁵"`. I would like to transform it to `"n5"`. For the string `"n⁵"`, i am not using any `<sup></sup>` tags. It is exactly like you see it.

Comment: Please provide us with some code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace each character, you can assemble all the superscript characters in an ordered string (so that `⁰` is at index 0, `¹` is at index 1, etc.) and get their corresponding digit by `indexOf`:

```
function digitFromSuperscript(superChar) {
    var result = "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹".indexOf(superChar);
    if(result > -1) { return result; }
    else { return superChar; }
}
```

You can then run each character in your string through this function. For example, you can do so by a `replace` callback:

```
"n⁵".replace(/./g, digitFromSuperscript)
```

Or more optimally, limit the replace to only consider superscript characters:

```
"n⁵".replace(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]/g, digitFromSuperscript)
```

Comment: @searlea you're right, sorry. I deleted it when I spotted it. This is a good answer regardless

Comment: Thanks mate, this is a clean solution

Comment: the question says "for example" but also says "number" so I would think @apsillers's answer would work.  It's better than mine, I was going to say,
`"5".charCodeAt(0) = unicode 53
String.fromCharCode(8309) = ⁵`
so just need to add/subtract 8256 from the uni-code to switch between. :)

Comment: As a (premature) optimisation note: this code calls back and runs the function for every character in the input text.  It might be more efficient to limit it so you only process the superscripts: e.g. `text.replace(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]/g, digitFromSuperscript)`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing fancy: you can replace the `⁵` character with the `5` character.

```js
var result = "n⁵".replace("⁵", "5");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes this. As far as I know there's no reverse method for .sup() so you'll have to manually parse the text and do a replace for each digit (0-9) to get a string you can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex replacement with a replacement function:

```js
function replaceSupers(str) {
  var superMap = {
    '⁰': '0',
    '¹': '1',
    '²': '2',
    '³': '3',
    '⁴': '4',
    '⁵': '5',
    '⁶': '6',
    '⁷': '7',
    '⁸': '8',
    '⁹': '9'
  }

  return str.replace(/[⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹]/g, function(match) {
    return superMap[match];
  });
}

console.log(replaceSupers('a¹²n⁴⁵lala⁷⁸⁹'));
```